# Mysqldb and Python KeyError Handling

Tags: python, mysql, sql-insert, mysql-python

I am attempting to add multiple values to MySQL table, here's the code:

```
Try:
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO companies_and_charges_tmp (etags, company_id,  created, delivered, satisfied, status, description, persons_entitled) VALUES ('%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s')" % (item['etag'], ch_no, item['created_on'], item['delivered_on'], item['satisfied_on'], item['status'], item['particulars'][0]['description'], item['persons_entitled'][0]['name']))

Except KeyError:
    pass
```

The problem is that this code is in the loop and at times one of the values that are beiing inserted will be missing, which will result in Key Error cancelling the entire insertion.

How do I get past the KeyError, so when the KeyError relating to one of the items that are being inserted occurs, others are still added to the table and the one that is missing is simply left as NULL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`dict.get()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) which would return `None` if a key would not be found in a dictionary. `MySQL` driver would then convert `None` to `NULL` during the query parameterization step:

```
# handling description and name separately
try:
    description = item['particulars'][0]['description']
except KeyError:
    description = None

# TODO: violates DRY - extract into a reusable method?
try:
    name = item['persons_entitled'][0]['name']
except KeyError:
    name = None

cursor.execute("""
     INSERT INTO 
         companies_and_charges_tmp 
         (etags, company_id,  created, delivered, satisfied, status, description, persons_entitled) 
     VALUES 
         (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""", 
     (item.get('etag'), ch_no, item.get('created_on'), item.get('delivered_on'), item.get('satisfied_on'), item.get('status'), description, name))
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you! Just curious, why did you have to handle description and name separately?

Comment: Sorry, I said this too early. Now when I am runing it through the loop I am getting this error: local variable 'item' referenced before assignment

Comment: @KamilMieczakowski had to handle the name and description separately since it involves getting items from subdictionaries..as for the error, make sure u have 'item' defined before u are using it. Thanks.

Comment: thank you. Unfortunately I am struggling with how to reference the item variable, hence I published another question. If you could help since you know the context I would be grateful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37377695/mysqldb-error-local-variable-referenced-before-assignment-different-than-usual